# Java AWT Stops listening to input after random lengths of time

Tags: java, awt

(Sorry I can't get a working E.g. of the issue, I need help for my help!)

I'm in the process of creating a custom game engine and have come upon an issue whereby while the game is running - the game stops taking input

I've checked and the program seems to continue running in the background. It also doesn't seem to vary with different machines
(My main device is a Mac Book Pro 2011)

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Focus extends JFrame implements KeyListener {   
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        char currKey = '\0';
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {public void run() {new UIManager();}});
        }
        public Focus() throws IOException {     
            Container contentPane = getContentPane();
            contentPane.add(new DrawCanvas());
            addKeyListener(this);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            pack();
            setFocusable(true);
            setVisible(true);
        }    
        private class DrawCanvas extends JPanel {                   
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;   
            public void paintComponent(Graphics pen) {
                //Drawloop
                if(currKey == 'k') {
                    //This is the code that randomly stops running
                    System.out.println("Yo");
                }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                repaint();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            currKey = e.getKeyChar();
        }
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            currKey = '\0';
        }
        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {   
        }
}
```

The code looks right to me (But then, it always does) and the only possible tripping point is that AWT is Instantiated in Main, Run in UIManager and the movement code resides in player though I don't know enough about AWT to know whether this would be the case and relocating the code in a backup lead to a program crash. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you create a small MVCE that shows the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was an issue with Java and MacOS key repeats- fixed in a newer Java version

To fix update java